# python: for loop through a lists of lists in or change data to 2 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm struggling a bit with python. I have a tab delimited text file that looks like:

```
SNP Name    ss715583617 ss715592335 ss715591044 ss7155(98181
Chromosome  Gm02    Gm05    Gm05    Gm07
Position    5581696 6943050 34695858    43520803
Cultivar Name               
PI065549    T   A   A   T
PI081762    T   A   A   T
PI101404A   T   A   A   T
PI101404B   T   A   A   T
```

I need to read the line: SNP Name into one array, Chromosome into one array, omit position, omit Cultivar Name. then place the data that starts with PI065549 T A A T into a 2 D array some how. What I have with python is the data in a list of lists. My questions are :

1. From my code, do I have my data into a list of lists?
2. How can I iterate through the list of lists with index position to analyze the Data? For my analysis its important do be able to do column wise analysis on it.

My main objective is to analyze the data by a column wise analysis to convert the chars to integers depending some conditions.

My code so far is:

```
snpNames = [] #to hold snp names(column titles) 
chrm = [] #to hold chr, needed later for random sampling 
numLines = 0; # to determine how many lines in the files, needed to     determine size of 2 d array 

snps = [[]] ## store the snp data in a list of lists...

with open("/home/dfreese/Desktop/testSNPtext") as file: 

    #read in the first line these contain the names and store into an array 
    firstLine = file.readline().strip()
    for i in firstLine.split("\t"): 
        snpNames.append(i)

    #second line contains the chr data, read that into the chr array
    secondLine = file.readline().strip()
    for i in secondLine.split("\t"):
        chrm.append(i)


     ## read in the remaining lines and fill in the 2 d array    
    for line in lines: 
        snps.append(line.strip().split("\t"))

file.close()


#check that the data is ok 
for i in snps: 
    print (i)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm used to coding in C++ and Java but for this data analysis Python was requested and I'm a bit stuck. Any suggestions or improvements would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: snps doesn't need to be declared like this.: `snps = [[]]`, you should be fine with `snps = []`. That said, it seems fine to me. To access your elements, you should be able to use  `snps[row][col]`. Then, if you want something more advanced, or you'll have to deal often with similar tasks you should look at [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/index.html). And since you are there, look also into [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/index.html).

Comment: Is your file actually tab delimited?

Comment: yes it is tab delimited as well.

Comment: Then pandas is definitely what you should be looking at, what are you doing with the `Cultivar Name ` line?

Answer (score 0):

> From my code, do I have my data into a list of lists?

Yes you do.  However, you don't need to do `snps = [[]]`.  `snps = []` is sufficient.

> How can I iterate through the list of lists with index position to analyze the Data?

```
for i, item in enumerate(snps):
    print(i, item)

Output:    
0 ['T', 'A', 'A', 'T']
1 ['T', 'A', 'A', 'T']
2 ['T', 'A', 'A', 'T']
...
```

---

If the first item in the `Cultiver Name` column is unique, you might consider using a dictionary (`{}`) instead:

```
snps = {}

...

for line in lines:
    row_vals = line.strip().split('\t')
    snps[row_vals[0]] = row_vals[1:]
```

Accessing the items in the Dictionary are now done like so:

```
print(snps['PI065549'])

Ouput:
['T', 'A', 'A', 'T']
```

If you're planning on doing any type of analysis, you might consider using `pandas`.  Here's a [quick intro](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) which also talks about [importing text files](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table)

Comment: thanks! well that Culitvar line needs to be omitted actually i dont need that data at all. and the objective is to do a column wise analysis, in other words to check if for each column in the 2d array if T is the dominat char, or if A is the dominat char. That's why I thought a 2 d array would be better than a dictionary. Would you still recommend pandas in this case? Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean by `dominate char`?

Comment: so in the first column of your output: really the data is 479 lines of T's,A's, G, and I need to count each letter and determine which has the highest count for each column of data. char i was just thinking in java or c++ it looks like a "char" variable b/c of the single quotations.

Comment: @DannyFreese then pandas is probably your best option honestly.

Answer (score 0):

you were almost there (this is python3.4, hope that's ok)

```
from pathlib import Path

DATA_PATH = Path(__file__).parent / '../data/chromosome.txt'

snpNames = [] #to hold snp names(column titles) 
chrm = [] #to hold chr, needed later for random sampling 
numLines = 0; # to determine how many lines in the files, needed to
              # determine size of 2 d array 

snps_dict = {} ## store the snp data in a list of lists...
snps = []

with DATA_PATH.open('r') as file:
     #read in the first line these contain the names and store into an array 
    firstLine = file.readline().strip()
    for i in firstLine.split(): 
        snpNames.append(i)

    #second line contains the chr data, read that into the chr array
    secondLine = file.readline().strip()
    for i in secondLine.split():
        chrm.append(i)

     ## read in the remaining lines and fill in the 2 d array    
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line.startswith('Position'):
            continue
        elif line.startswith('Cultivar Name'):
            continue
        splt = line.split()     
        snps[splt[0]] = splt[1:]
        snps.append(splt)

print(snpNames)
print(chrm)
print(snps_dict)
print(snps)
```

which yields:

```
['SNP', 'Name', 'ss715583617', 'ss715592335', 'ss715591044', 
 'ss7155(98181']
['Chromosome', 'Gm02', 'Gm05', 'Gm05', 'Gm07']
{'PI065549': ['T', 'A', 'A', 'T'], 'PI101404A': ['T', 'A', 'A', 'T'], 
 'PI081762': ['T', 'A', 'A', 'T'], 'PI101404B': ['T', 'A', 'A', 'T']}
[['PI065549', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'T'], ['PI081762', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'T'], 
 ['PI101404A', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'T'], ['PI101404B', 'T', 'A', 'A', 'T']]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I'm wondering my analysis it's really pending on doing a column wise analysis, isn't your suggestion in a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tab delimited file you can use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to create a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/home/dfreese/Desktop/testSNPtext"),delimiter="\t",header=None,names=["a","b","c","d","e"]))
```

Which should give you a dataframe something like:

```
                   a            b            c            d             e
0       SNP Name  ss715583617  ss715592335  ss715591044  ss7155(98181
1     Chromosome         Gm02         Gm05         Gm05          Gm07
2       Position      5581696      6943050     34695858      43520803
3  Cultivar Name          NaN          NaN          NaN           NaN
4       PI065549            A            A            T           NaN
5       PI081762            A            A            T           NaN
6      PI101404A            A            A            T           NaN
7      PI101404B            A            A            T           NaN
```

To get the last four rows together:

```
 print(df.iloc[4:8])
           a  b  c  d    e
4   PI065549  A  A  T  NaN
5   PI081762  A  A  T  NaN
6  PI101404A  A  A  T  NaN
7  PI101404B  A  A  T  NaN
```

Comment: wow, yeah i'll try that, thanks, i'm such a newbie to python'

Comment: For what you are doing, it is pretty much tailor-made. You will need to pip install it to use it but it makes a lot of jobs very simple.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to for loop through each column to determine which is the most abundant letter for each column. I'm a bit confused on how to use a forloop with pandas.

Comment: you want the count of the letters for each row or column?

Comment: each column. I need to count them for each column then eventually replace those results with an integer value, but analyze all the columns separately.